# How do I check if a string contains all repeated letters in Java?

Tags: java

For example the string `abba` contains all repeated letters, for this kinds of strings I need to be able to return a certain value. I have the following code, but this only tells me if strings like "aaaa" contain ALL the same letters, and doesn't work for strings containing repeating letters of two types.

```
public static boolean checkAllRepeated(String input)
    {
        char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
        int[] counts = new int[chars.length];

        int n = input.length();
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            if (chars[i] != chars[0])
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: There are many systems to solve this problem. What have you tried yet?

Comment: Can you just please write a working solution for this problem, I've been tearing my hair out for hours unable to figure out how to do it. But I've attempting splitting the string into character arrays and comparing them, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a system to solve student home work. Sorry, You didn't understood the purpose of the site

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52101/how-to-respond-to-people-just-asking-for-code-without-any-own-effort

Comment: if i understand, you just need to add another loop inside your loop , to compare each character with all the characters , so if any character occur one time return false .

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want your function to return `false` if your input string contains characters which occur only once?

```
public static boolean checkAllRepeated(String input)
{
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (Character c : input.toCharArray()){
        map.putIfAbsent(c, 0);
        map.put(c, map.get(c)+1);
    }
    return map.values().stream().noneMatch(i -> i == 1);
}
```

Comment: the last stream can be simplified to `map.values().stream().noneMatch(i -> i == 1)`

Comment: I took it even further :) `input.chars().boxed().collect(groupingBy(c -> c, counting())).values().stream().noneMatch(v -> v == 1)`. I had to use `boxed()` as `IntStream` doesn't have `collect()` method which accepts `Collector` - I don't like it but didn't dig further into it.

Answer (score 1):

A map should make it easy,

```
String input = "aabbcc";

Map<Character, Integer> unique = new HashMap<>();
for(Character aChar : input.toCharArray()){
   if(unique.get(aChar) != null) {unique.put(aChar, unique.get(aChar) + 1);}
    else { unique.put(aChar, 1); } 
}
if(unique.containsValue(1)){System.out.println("no duplicates"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

for a String where only one char is not repeated i.e. occurrence of one character is odd then you can follow the XOR operation

```
public char solution(char[] cs) {
        if (cs.length > 0) {
            int i;
            int res = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
                res = res ^ cs[i];
            }
            return (char) res;
        }
        return (char) -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

as i understand if just one character not repeated then return false, this will work for that purpose.

```
public static boolean checkAllRepeated(String input)
        {
            char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
            int counts;

            int n = input.length();
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
                counts =1;
                 for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                  if (j != i  && chars[i] == chars[j]) counts++;
                }
    if(counts==1)return false;

        }
            return true;
        }
```